# Android: Shuffle variables and multiple setText

Tags: java, android, arrays

**My code/situation:**

I have four objects of the class **String**, named from `mQuestionAnswer1` to `mQuestionAnswer4`. Right now, they are displayed in four TextViews in a very simple way of: `tvQuestionAnswer1.setText(mQuestionAnswer1)` etc.

Also I need to mention, that the answers are clickable and they are checked, for example when user clicks answer no 1, it triggers listener and calls `checkAnswer(1)`.

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to shuffle the answers so they don't get displayed every time in the same position.

I have some solution in mind, but I think it is a little overcomplicated and I'd appreciate if you help me clarify this issue.

**Idea:**

I set up array:

`int[] answersArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};`

and shuffle it with my Fisher-Yates method called `shuffleArray()`:

`shuffleArray(answersArray);`

After this, I get shuffled array and this is where the problem begins. I don't know how to display the `mQuestionAnswer1` in TextViews. I could run *for* loop and *if else* but that would probably be tremendous exaggeration.

Checking the answer should be probably easier (should...). When user clicks answer no 1, I think I am going to do something like: `checkAnswer(answersArray[0])`.

Is this the correct approach? Do you have any idea how to quickly display the `mQuestionAnswer`s? All tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: how is your data model associating a question and an Answer???

Comment: @Xoce I get that from my database with AsyncTask and pass the values to `mQuestionAnswer1 ... 4` and `mCorrectAnswer`. When the answers get clicked, I have 4 listeners, each for every TextView. They call `checkAnswer(1) ... (4)` and the function compares the argument of `checkAnswer` with `mCorrectAnswer`.

Comment: ok...  I will post right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be address in many different ways, so I will post my first thoughts...

you can use collections, (because they can be sorted):
what you need:

1. define a list with the answer
2. Shuffle the list...
3. populate you textviews
4. set the listeners
5. you can check the answer by getting the text on every view

## The final Snippet can look like:

---

```
List<String> myAnswerList = new ArrayList<>(String);
myAnswerList.add(answer1);
myAnswerList.add(answer2);
myAnswerList.add(answer3);
myAnswerList.add(answer4);

// now mixed up
Collections.shuffle(myAnswerList);

tvQuestionAnswer1.setText(myAnswerList.get(0));
tvQuestionAnswer2.setText(myAnswerList.get(1));
tvQuestionAnswer3.setText(myAnswerList.get(2));
tvQuestionAnswer4.setText(myAnswerList.get(3));

// set the onClickListeners

//and in the onClick
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    checkAnswer(tvQuestionAnswer1.getText());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although, you wrote `mQuestionAnswer1` after shuffling the answers and putting them in `myAnswerList` - I believe you mentioned values from myAnswerList. How do I access those certain values from that List?

Comment: you are right thanx... :) do this. myAnswerList.get(0); and you will get the first elemnt of the list...  myAnswerList.get(1); for the 2nd etc etc

Comment: Thank you again. Still it doesn't really solve my problem since my argument in `checkAnswer()` is a integer (answer id [1..4]), not the text. But I get the idea and I will try to use `Collections.shuffle` on some kind of... `List<Map<String,Integer>>` maybe? I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: Had to change my `checkAnswer()` method a bit, but your answer is definitely correct here. Thank you a lot. :) All works now!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the answers into an array and shuffle them. The same listener can be used for all of the textViews.

```
  TextView textView1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
    textView2...

    String[] answersArray={........};

    shuffle(answersArray);

    textView1.setText(answersArray[0]);
    textView2.setText(answersArray[1]);
    textView3.setText(answersArray[2]);
    textView4.setText(answersArray[3]);

    View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView textView= (TextView) v;

            checkAnswer(textView.getText());
        }
    };

    textView1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textView2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textView3.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textView4.setOnClickListener(listener);
```